# events javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to display a message on mouse click. But I also need another message to be displayed on the next mouse click. The problem is that in my code both messages appear on the first mouse click.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script>
                function myfunction()
                {
                var obj=document.getElementById("msg1");
                obj.innerHTML="message1";
                if(obj.innerHTML=="message1")
                {
                    var obj1=document.getElementById("msg2");
                    obj1.innerHTML="message2";
                }

                }
            </script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="msg">
                <form name="myform">
                    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="myfunction()">
                        <p id="msg1"></p>
                        <p id="msg2"></p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please spell check and spend additional time formatting both your writing as well as your code!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var flag=0;            
function myfunction()
            {
            if (flag==0)
            {
            var obj=document.getElementById("msg1");
            obj.innerHTML="message1";
            flag=1;}
            else
            {
                var obj1=document.getElementById("msg2");
                obj1.innerHTML="message2";
            }

            }
</script>
```

Comment: what should i do, if i need to display more messages the same way

Comment: One way is, you keep on increasing the flag value and check. Not the neatest of ways, but will do the job. Oh and if this solved your query, please accept the answer by clicking on the little tick.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (obj.innerHTML == "message1") {
  var obj1 = document.getElementById("msg2");
  obj1.innerHTML = "message2";
}else{
  obj.innerHTML = "message1";
}
```

Your if would always execute because you were trying to check if `obj.innerHTML == "message1"` immediately after setting it to that.

Comment: yes i need message1 to be displayed every time i click.but message2 should be displayed only on the next mouse click.thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Do you see that you set the innerhtml of obj to "message1" and then immediately after you check if the innerHTML is "message1"  that will always be true.

You need to change the if.  So it says:

```
if(obj.innterHTML=="message1"){
  obj.innerHTML="message2";
} else {
  obj.innerHTML="message1";
}
```

Comment: yes i need message1 to be displayed every time i click.but message2 should be displayed only on the next mouse click

Answer (score 0):

Similar to others, but what the heck:

```
    var obj1 = document.getElementById('msg1');
    var obj2 = document.getElementById('msg2');

    if (obj1.innerHTML == '') {
      obj1.innerHTML = 'message1';
    } else {
      obj2.innerHTML = 'message2';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunction() {
  var i, ele;
  for(i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
     ele = document.getElementById("msg"+i);
     if (ele && ele.innerHTML.length == 0) {
         ele.innerHTML = 'message' + i;
         return;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a click counter to check it was first click or more then first.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        var $clickCount = 0;
        function myfunction() {
            $clickCount++;
            var obj = document.getElementById("msg1");
            obj.innerHTML = "message1";
            if (obj.innerHTML == "message1") {
                var obj1 = document.getElementById("msg2");
                if ($clickCount == 2) {
                    obj1.innerHTML = "message2";
                }

            }

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="msg">
        <form name="myform">
            <input type="button" value="click" onclick="myfunction()">
            <p id="msg1"></p>
            <p id="msg2"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```